# Signers vs Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

We are integrating our BPM application with Docusign. We have a document which should be signed by n individuals. Should we have multiple recipient tags or just 1 recipient tag with multiple signer tags inside that? What would be the difference between both the approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Each Recipient object has properties that identify a specific signer including a property that represents the signer's name, for example). Your "Create Envelope" API request will need to include a separate Recipient object for each Signer -- and then, for each recipient, you'll  specify tags that belong to the recipient.   (The other approach you describe -- i.e., facilitating multiple people signing an envelope by specifying only one recipient with multiple 'sign here' tags -- is not feasible under any circumstances.)

For example, the **recipients** structure that represents two Signers, each having one place to sign and one text box to complete, would look something like this:

```
"recipients": {
  "signers": [
   {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "clientUserId": "123",
      "tabs":{
            "signHereTabs":[
                {
                    "tabLabel":"BSign1",
                    "documentId": "1", 
                    "pageNumber": "1", 
                    "xPosition": "200", 
                    "yPosition": "200"
                }
            ],
            "textTabs":[
               {
                    "tabLabel":"BorrowerPhone",
                    "value":"717-717-7171",
                    "documentId": "1", 
                    "pageNumber": "1", 
                    "xPosition": "100", 
                    "yPosition": "100"
               }
            ]
         }
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "email": "janesemail@outlook.com",
      "recipientId": "2",
      "routingOrder": "2",
      "clientUserId": "567",
      "tabs":{
            "signHereTabs":[
                {
                    "tabLabel":"CBSign1",
                    "documentId": "1", 
                    "pageNumber": "2", 
                    "xPosition": "200", 
                    "yPosition": "200"
                }
            ],
            "textTabs":[
               {
                    "tabLabel":"Co-BorrowerPhone",
                    "value":"111-222-3333",
                    "documentId": "1", 
                    "pageNumber": "2", 
                    "xPosition": "100", 
                    "yPosition": "100"
               }
            ]
         }
    }
  ]
}
```

Taking some time to review the information (and code samples) on the DocuSign Developer Center (https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) and within the REST API Guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf) would be time well spent.